# HighCharts Pattern Fill with multi-color series - Export issue

Tags: highcharts

I'm using HighCharts [Pattern Fill plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/9/Pattern-Fill) to apply different patterns for each data bar in a Bar chart. Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ravinsp/tme364td/

```
var rawdata = [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4];
var datapoints = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

  datapoints.push({
    y: rawdata[i],
    color: 'url(#highcharts-default-pattern-' + (i % 10) + ')'
  });
}

$('#container').highcharts({
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 50 * 12
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Export and resize to see the issue'
  },

  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },

  series: [{
    data: datapoints
  }]

});
```

In Chrome only, if I **Export the chart** and then attempt to **resize the chart**, the pattern bars disappear. They are still there in the DOM svg but just not visually rendered. The actual exported image is correct. This only happens in **Chrome**. No issues on  Firefox and IE Edge.

This only occurs if you use individual colors for each data point. This issue does not occur in charts with a single pattern for the entire series (eg. http://jsfiddle.net/9KtwA/1/).

Have anybody else encountered this issue?

Comment: Thank you for reporting. Indeed looks like an issue, so I added this information to our tracker here: https://github.com/highcharts/pattern-fill/issues/19